# How do I connect items from one parse method to another?

Tags: scrapy

'''

```
    import scrapy
    from ..items import GooddealItem

    class FarmtoolsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'farmtools'
        allowed_domains = ['www.gooddeal.com']
        start_urls = ['https://www.gooddeal.com/all? 
        source=private&sort=publishdate%20desc']

        def parse(self, response):

            items = GooddealItem()

            rows = response.xpath('//ul[@class="card-collection"]/li')

            for row in rows:
                link = row.xpath('.//a/@href').get() #this is the full link.
                link_split = link.split('/')[-1] #this splits the url link th first time.
                linkid = link_split.split('?')[0] #this splits it the second time.
                title = row.xpath('.//div[1]/p[@class="card__body-title"]/text()').get()
                county = row.xpath('.//a/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul[@class="card__body-keyinfo"]/li[contains(text(),"min")]/following-sibling::node()/text()').get()
                price = row.xpath('.//p[@class="card__price"]/span[1]/text()').get()
                subcat = row.xpath('.//a/div/div[2]/div[1]/p[2]/text()[2]').get()
                zero = row.xpath('.//a/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul[@class="card__body-keyinfo"]/li[contains(text(),"min")]/text()').get()
                if zero == '0 min':

                     items['linkid'] = linkid
                     items['title'] = title
                     items['county'] = county
                     items['price'] = price
                     items['subcat'] = subcat
                     items['zero'] = zero
                     items['link'] = link

                    yield response.follow(url = link, callback=self.parse_item_page)

        def parse_item_page(self, response):

            items = GooddealItem()

            rows = response.xpath('/html/body[1]')

            for row in rows:
                category = row.xpath('.//main/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/nav/span/a[1]/span/text()').get(),
                views = row.xpath('.//main/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/span[2]/text()').get(),
                seller_id = row.xpath('.//main/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a/@href').get(),
                seller_ads = row.xpath('.//main/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/dl[3]/dd/text()').get(),
                lifetime_ads = row.xpath('//main/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/dl[4]/dd/text()').get()

                items['category'] = category
                items['views'] = views
                items['seller_id'] = seller_id
                items['seller_ads'] = seller_ads
                items['lifetime_ads'] = lifetime_ads

                yield items
```

'''
I'm stuck on this as it's my first attempt. When I run the code I'm just getting back:

2020-07-12 22:53:21 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 [https://www.gooddeal.com/dogs-for-sale/dachshunds/25348559>](https://www.gooddeal.com/dogs-for-sale/dachshunds/25348559%3E)
{'category': (None,),
'lifetime_ads': None,
'seller_ads': (None,),
'seller_id': (None,),
'views': (None,)}

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Hi @billiam, when asking question please add more details **explaining** what you need, what you have tried and what isn't working. This always helps in getting more comprehensible and useful answers. Let me know if my answer bellow helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the data scraped in `parse` method to be joined together with the data scraped in the `parse_item_page`.

**If you are using Scrapy v1.7+** you can use [cb_kwargs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.cb_kwargs) when building the request.

This parameter receives a dict with arbitrary data that will be used as argument in the callback function. So you would have to do something like this in your request:

```
        ...
        yield response.follow(url = link, callback=self.parse_item_page, cb_kwargs={'scraped_item': items})
```

For this to work, you also need to change the callback function to receive this parameter. Like this:

```
    def parse_item_page(self, response, scraped_item):
        ...
```

Scrapy will take care of sending the `scraped_item` when calling the `parse_item_page`.

**If you are using Scrapy v1.6 or older:**

You will need to use the [meta](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) parameter. This method still works in more recent versions, but `cb_kwargs`(solution above) are preferable.

When building the request you will use the meta parameter to include some arbitrary data in the request. The data will be accessible in the response object that the callback function receives. Your request should look like this:

```
        ...
        yield response.follow(url = link, callback=self.parse_item_page, meta={'scraped_item': items})
```

In this case you will access the data by calling `response.meta`:

```
    def parse_item_page(self, response):
        items = response.meta.get('scraped_item') #response.meta is a dict
        ...
```

Comment: Why is cb_kwargs perferable ? do you happen to know what was the rationale for changing from meta to cb_kwargs ? I'll be writing it down to look up the code to see if I can work it out, but just curious.

Comment: I mentioned it's preferable because it's stated so in Scrapy docs. I'd argue that is preferable because it makes code more comprehensible as the parameter is explicitly passed into the callback function, instead of implicit in `response.meta`. Also, `response.meta` makes use of special keys internally, which could be misused or mistakenly overwritten by an unaware user.